# obtener la fecha de creacion en archivo en Consulta Linq

Tags: c#, linq, filesystem

tengo la siguiente consulta y necesito obtener la fecha de creación de cada archivo...

```
                    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(restrictionsFolderPath);
                string dateName = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateNameFormat);
                restrictionsFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
                                    where f.Name.Contains(fileExtension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                                    f.Name.Contains(dateName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                                    !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)
                                    select f).FirstOrDefault();
```

la idea que en los archivos que se obtienen en el directory no tome el datetime now sino el:
`string dateName = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateNameFormat);`

con la instruccion File.GetLastWriteTime de cada uno de los archivos...

Comment: No queda del todo claro el dato que estas buscando obtener.. La última fecha de modificación de cada archivo? de la carpeta contenedora? que fecha buscas?

Comment: ¿`f.Name.Contains(fileExtension)` no debería ser un `EndsWith`?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal SI estoy buscando la ultima fecha de modificacion de cada archivo! en la carpeta contenedora, esa es la fecha que Busco!

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no busco si termina ends o filee

Comment: @ger buscas si un archivo contiene una extensión. Si usas `Contains` te puede dar positivo en archivos `es.un.archivo.txt` como en `data.un` para un `Contains(@".un")`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster si tambien esta bien tu aporte, este codigo me asignaron para modificar que seleccione los que tengan los archivos con la ultima fecha de modificacion.

Comment: Por lo que se ve tu código ya hace lo que quieres hacer, ¿cuál esta siendo tu problema?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal el problema es que toma la fecha actual con el DateTime.NOW y se requiere que tome la fecha de modificación del archivo. posiblemente con la instruccion FILE.GetLastWriteTime, pero no se como implementarlo en la consulta LINQ

Comment: Pero qué cosa toma el datetime.now? en tu código, dentro del resultado, cada elemento dentro de `restrictionsFile` tendrá en la propiedad `GetLastWriteTime` el valor correcto, de la última escritura..

Comment: los archivos están nombrados con la fecha de modificación por ejemplo const20191003.txt pero si están con el datetime.now asumía que era archivo del now pero cuando llegan a  las 00:00 (el datetime asume fecha 20191004.txt) se debe tomar el archivo de ultima modificación (es lo que veo que evitaría no tomar el archivo) y SI lo que dices de cada elemento dentro del restrictionsFile se debe obtener la ultima modificación del archivo.